# Pkg snapshot folder

Tags: zeit-pkg

The [Pkg CLI](https://github.com/zeit/pkg) packages node.js applications into executables.

At runtime, the application should access assets from the global `/snapshots/` folder (or `C:\snapshots\` on Windows).

- Does this mean only one `Pkg` app can run at the same time, due to sharing the one snapshots directory?
- Does this make the program require admin/sudo privileges?
- What happens if the snapshots directory already exists and is being used for other stuff?
- Why did they decide on having a global directory?
- Are there ways of not using this directory?

I can't find any information on this, and it just doesn't seem right...